# database driven content and locale

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I can make my pages to be multilingual by selecting a language file based on the language selected by a user which changes the locale so I can only change parts of the page's text to a different language - is there a way change the entire page's content or the rest of the content that is databased driven to a different language like a translator but without using an iframe translator.

Is there a script you can add to change the text to a specific language by a user selection. If you know could you please provide an example or a link to a tutorial for me please, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered you considered trying something like the library below? As long as you have you translation files set up in english, It can translate them to other languages automatically.

https://github.com/ben182/laravel-auto-translate